# Can't import localforage into a Injectable service

Tags: angular, typescript, localforage

I'm trying to use `localforage` library into my Angular 4 project.

I've already done:

npm install localforage --save

This is my Injectable service

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {localForage} from "localforage";

constructor(){}

    setAccessToken(aToken:string){
        localForage.setItem('accessToken', aToken)
    }

    getAccessToken(){
        return localForage.getItem('accessToken')
    }
```

This return son `npm start`:

```
error TS2305: Module '"localforage"' has no exported member 'localForage'.
```

What would be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your import should look like:

```
import * as localForage from  "localforage";
```

Comment: With this I still get `Cannot find module 'localforage' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the `localForage` [github readme](https://github.com/localForage/localForage).

> TypeScript
>
> If you have the allowSyntheticDefaultImports compiler option set to true in your tsconfig.json (supported in TypeScript v1.8+), you should use:
>
> ```
> import localForage from "localforage";
> ```
>
> Otherwise you should use one of the following:
>
> ```
> import * as localForage from "localforage";
> // or, in case that the typescript version that you are using
> // doesn't support ES6 style imports for UMD modules like localForage
> import localForage = require("localforage");
> ```